Can はくmean "to clean"?
I see that this verb is supposed to mean "to wear". I am using rosetta and it's being used for cleaning up messes. Am I crazy, or this is a mistake on Rosetta's end?


Many words can have multiple meanings. Please refer to a dictionary in the first instance: https://jisho.org/search/%E6%8E%83%E3%81%8F

Ah I had missed it can mean "to sweep".

For future readers, this verb is written 掃く in kanji.
